# Spring framework/Eclipse RCP integration with Blueprint Gemini

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, osgi, spring-dm, eclipse-gemini

I am trying to integrate Spring framework into my Eclipse RCP application.

I was not able to find relevant documentation on how to integrate Blueprint Gemini into my RCP application. Do I just add the Gemini jars to my RCP project? I guess this is not sufficient... Then how do I add the Gemini jars as a plugin? How do I start the extender properly?

Can anyone please provide guidelines or pointers?

After following Francis Upton's advice and selecting the jars for the target platform using **directory** I am now able to view **org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender** in the run configuration.

However I now get the following error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender_1.0.0.RELEASE [36]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint; version="[1.0.0.RELEASE,1.0.0.RELEASE]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to install Gemini into your target platform (you can work with your target platform using Preferences -> Plugin Development -> Target Platform.

Once installed in the target platform, since these are OSGi bundles, you should be able to reference them like anything else (using the Dependencies section of the plugin manifest).

Comment: Thanks Francis, The issue I still have is that at no point do I see the following plugin: **org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender** appear in my target (dependencies).

Comment: When you add your target platform (and you can just add a new target platform), specify "Directory" instead of the default "Installation". Using "Directory" will find every plugin that's actually in the directory. It would be the software was not installed properly in your target platform.

Comment: I am making progess. I can now see **org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender** in the plugins tab of the run configuration. I am now get this: `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender_1.0.0.RELEASE [36]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint; version="[1.0.0.RELEASE,1.0.0.RELEASE]"`

Comment: After installing a product definition, I was able to get rid of the above exception. I now have other errors but they are not relevant to this question so I will open another question. Thanks again to Francis.